# How does Heroku knows which file use to deploy?

Tags: heroku, deployment

I always create a file called `server.js` as entry point of my Node.js app and I always deploy to Heroku with that file but... How does Heroku know that `server.js` the file that it should to execute?

What if my server file is called `anotherName.js`? How can I tell to Heroku to deploy `anotherName.js`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a `Procfile`, Heroku will look there first.

If no `Procfile` exists, [Heroku will try to run the `start` sript defined in your `package.json`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs#specifying-a-start-script).

> What if my server file is called `anotherName.js`? How can I tell to Heroku to deploy `anotherName.js`?

Either by modifying (or creating) your `Procfile` or by changing the `start` script in your `package.json`.